# Owl Carousel not centered when window is smaller than ~650px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

*I'm already sorry for not providing a code snippet, but I can't reproduce the problem there.*

---

So, I made a "carousel" with [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). Everything is working perfectly, but when the window is smaller than something around 650px, it's not centered anymore.

With Owl Carousel you got the option to center it with the option `center:true`. That's working perfectly on bigger screens, but when I look at it on my smartphone for example, the "centered" item shifts to the right.

That's my structure:

```
<div class="owl">
  <div>06:00</div>
  <div>07:00</div>
  <div>08:00</div>
  <div>09:00</div>
  <div>10:00</div>
  <div>11:00</div>
  <div>12:00</div>
  ...
</div>
```

And I am using this CSS:

```
.owl, .owl-stage{
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;

  .owl-item{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
  }
}
```

So nothing special, but still it decides to act weird.
To finish it off, [here you got a codepen](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/YaqJMz). *When you click a date in the calendar, the carousel shows up.*

I tested it in Chrome 64.0.3282.186 and Internet Explorer and both are giving me the same behaviour.

Comment: Try this [link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html) for items

Comment: @Pankaj Wow thanks... There was just not enough space for 5 items... Lowered it to 3 and it's working. If you wanna write an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code:

```
responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
        }
    }
```

You can manage items as per the browser size: `600:{` indicates the above browser size.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Working perfectly.

Comment: even [more](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) :)